# Continuous time ODE to Discrete time ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I've been working a bit with a continuous time ODE (the logistic equation) given by:

$$\frac{dx_i}{dt} = x_i(b_i-\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j)$$

I was looking at another paper which looks at the discrete time logistic equation which they give as:

$$x_i(k+1) = x_i(k)e^{[b_i-\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j(k)]}$$

I was wondering how one can derive this discrete time equation and if it would have the same properties as the continuous one? For example, I believe the fixed points of both systems are the same. But if one can prove a fact about one of the equations, does it automatically hold true for the other (like some sort of equivalence relation between the two?)

Comment: Using $\frac{1}{x_i}\frac{dx_i}{dt} = \frac{d\log x_i}{dt}$ and applying a simple first order discretization with unit step length, $\frac{df(k)}{dt} = f(k+1)-f(k)$, of the derivative gives the formula $\log(x_i(k+1)) - \log(x_i(k)) = b_i - \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j(k) \implies x_i(k+1) = x_i(k) e^{b_i - \sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j(k)}$

Comment: Ah yes, I should've been able to figure that out lol. Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way that is $\frac{df(k)}{dk}$, not $dt$.